# CDK init app unsuccessful even after root install

Tags: python, npm, aws-cdk

When attempting to initialise a new cdk project in a windows WSL environment, I was confronted with the following error:

```
cdk init test-app --language python
Usage:
  cdk [-vbo] [--toc] [--notransition] [--logo=<logo>] [--theme=<theme>] [--custom-css=<cssfile>] FILE
  cdk --install-theme=<theme>
  cdk --default-theme=<theme>
  cdk --generate=<name>
```

I first wanted to check the install was still correct but the version number is not displayed:

```
cdk --version
cdk
```

All advice online and on Stack Overflow suggests re-installing as root user. I have attempted a global install as root, followed by a restart:

```
sudo npm install -g aws-cdk
```

checking for global install version lists the following, showing the update has had global effect:

```
npm list -g --depth=0 | grep cdk
├── aws-cdk@2.15.0
├── cdk-assume-role-credential-plugin@1.4.0
```

but the error remains the same. Running the which command confirms it is following the correct user path:

```
which cdk
/home/user/.local/bin/cdk
```

This is a new error and I am unable to pinpoint any particular change that could have caused this. I have been able to initialise cdk projects in empty directories before without issue.

Comment: You have another file called `cdk` which is present in `/home/user/.local/bin/cdk` which seems to be hijacking. I'd recommend removing that file if you're sure that's not required

Comment: That got it. Very confusing as now there is no `cdk` file within the local bin folder. I am unsure how this double-install happened or which path it is currently using without it.